# Interference Between a Structure's :print-function and *print-readably* in Common Lisp?

Tags: data-structures, common-lisp, hashtable, sbcl, writefile

I'm trying to readably print a common lisp structure to a file so it can be read back in later. It appears SBCL has some rather sophisticated built-in facilities for readably printing complex objects, which may obviate having to write specialized print-object methods.

Is it possible that my structure's own `:print-function` is interfering with `*print-readably*`?

```
(defstruct (problem-state (:conc-name problem-state.) (:print-function print-problem-state) (:copier nil))
  "A planning state including the current propositional database."
  (name nil :type symbol)  ;last action executed
  (instantiations nil :type list)  ;from last action effect
  (happenings nil :type list)  ;a list of (object (next-index next-time next-direction)) pairs
  (time 0.0 :type real)
  (value 0.0 :type real)
  (heuristic 0.0 :type real)
  (idb (make-hash-table) :type hash-table)  ;integer hash table of propositions
  (hidb (make-hash-table) :type hash-table))  ;integer table for happening events
```

When executing

```
(defun save (object file)
  "Saves an object to a file so it can be read in later."
  (with-open-file (out-stream file :direction :output)
    (let ((*print-readably* t))
      (pprint object out-stream))))
```

for a structure instance, the result is human readable, but not lisp readable.

Do I need to somehow disable the `:print-function` (if this is the problem)?

Comment: You would need to see if it gets called. That should be easy to find out. If it gets called your print function would probably need to check how to print it? Your print function can examine the value of `*print-readably*` and use that knowledge...

Comment: The pretty printer probably has its own printer for structures.

Comment: OK right, the `:print-function` is being called and resetting `*print-readably*` to NIL. Maybe one way to handle this is to set a flag that the print-function checks to determine whether to print human readable or lisp readable (rebinding `*print-readably*`). This seems rather awkward tho, especially if the flag has to be a global variable.

Comment: See also https://github.com/conspack/cl-conspack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you provide a `:print-function` or `:print-object` option to `defstruct`, then the printer you designate will be used to print objects of that class.  *It's the responsibility of that function to deal with the printer control variables correctly.*  In particular this means that if `*print-readably*` is true it must either print the object readably or signal an error if it's not willing or unable to do so: it should not simply print the thing unreadably, and still less should it bind or assign to `*print-readably*` or anything like that.

[`print-unreadable-object`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_pr_unr.htm) can help you get this behaviour correct:

```
(defstruct (foo
            (:print-function (lambda (f s d)
                               (declare (ignore d))
                               (print-unreadable-object (f s :type t :identity t)
                                 ...))))
  ...)
```

will behave correctly, as `print-unreadable-object` is defined to signal a suitable error if `*print-readably*` is true.

If you want to be able to print a structure readably if need be but unreadably otherwise it is relatively hard to do this using the `:print-function` or `:print-object` mechanisms.  Your function clearly doesn't get this correct: I suspect few do.

Fortunately there is an easy answer, which is not to use these options, but define methods on `print-object`:

```
(defstruct foo
  x)

(defmethod print-object ((f foo) s)
  (if *print-readably*
      (call-next-method)
    (print-unreadable-object (f s :type t :identity t)
      (format s "x = ~A" (foo-x f)))))
```

And now

```
> *print-readably*
nil

> (let ((*print-readably* t))
    (print (make-foo)))

#S(foo :x nil) 
#<foo x = nil 8010058923>
```

Of course all the `:print-function` and `:print-object` mechanisms do is define stylized methods on `print-object` for you.  From [`defstruct`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm):

> The `:print-function` and `:print-object` options specify that a `print-object` method for structures of type structure-name should be generated.

Before CLOS (when `:print-object` didn't exist) `:print-function` did something in a more deeply magic way, but that's all been greatly simplified by CLOS.

Comment: Cogent explanation; works like a charm! Nicely complements the way SBCL can produce nested hash tables & structures readably.